# Do I need to caulk where my roof meets the siding?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing, siding

I'm not sure if the seam needs to be caulked where the roof meets my wood siding. There are some areas where it looks like it was once caulked but the majority of it does not look caulked. Should the seam be caulked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### NO on the caulk.

### Yes on ROOF SIDEWALL FLASHING.

Really easy.   There are tons of products or you can fabricate metal to work.   Most roofing companies will have their preference and it will depend on the siding materials and look you want.

You can go behind the siding like this.

[image]

To retro fit you can buy a product made for it or use a step flashing technique.

[image]

For yours if you just want to slap something on top you are looking at something like this.   (albeit this is just extending the water out, not creating a water barrier.   But going out 6" might not keep all moisture off your walls but will probably do a good enough job to not notice rot for 20+ years.  You can caulk the edges here and just leave a few gaps for air/run-off)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the siding/roofing was installed properly then metal flashing and tar should have been applied for waterproofing.

If you're having water issues when it rains then that could indicate something wasn't done right.

Caulking (preferably 100% silicone) shouldn't hurt the situation unless it ends up trapping moisture behind your siding which would have otherwise had an exit path.

Comment: there should be a corner strip of metal flashing behind that rake board, and under the siding.  And one behind the siding and coming out above the rake board.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, is the answer to your question, but the trim board must leave a 1/2” gap to allow for pine straw, leaves, and other debris not to get trapped between the roof and the bottom side of the trim board shown in your post (with blue siding).  The other posts show incorrect methods, and please do not try those or allow a contractor to use those!  The metal counter flashing is ok, but it could be improved.